# nested interval property $\implies$ monotone convergence theorem for real sequences

Tags: real-analysis

How can we prove the monotone convergence theorem for real sequences by using only the nested interval property ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be your sequence. Let $x$ be the supremum of your sequence. What does the Nested Interval Propety tell you about $\{[x_n,x]\}_{n=1}^\infty$?